# Create a timeline using UIScrollview with Swift 2.0

Tags: uiscrollview, swift2, timeline

Excuse me for this probably complex question.

I'm currently working on a feature for an app that needs to present a timeline of a location. I have had influences from the app "Path" which also uses a similar method although they have implemented it for social media (forgive me if there is other related examples). I also looked at [this](https://github.com/edekhayser/Timeline) example which I believe is the closest to my target but he creates the UI programatically which I haven't learn't how to do yet and am more used to using the storyboards. Therefore it may seem quite daunting to try an implement a similar method.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN6f4.png) is the layout I'm looking for where the 'Year' and 'Content' views relate to each other and the Content view adjust according to the amount of contents inside it i.e. text & images.

I really hope this isn't such a complicated ask but thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to use a custom table view cell with a dynamic view controller. You can create a placeholder for the year/info labels and fill the content through a dynamic table view's class.

Here's an example: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Storyboards_and_Swift_to_Build_Dynamic_TableViews_with_Prototype_Table_View_Cells